# FullCalendar Dynamic Import

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to import Full Calendar dynamically to only load it when needed and have the following:

```
    (async () => {
        console.log('Hello 0');
        const Calendar = await import('@fullcalendar/core');
        console.log('Hello 1');
        const { default: dayGridPlugin } = await import('@fullcalendar/daygrid');
        console.log('Hello 2');

        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')

        let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin]
        });
    })();
```

I can't see why this is failing. I just get the following error:

> vdom.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Please import the top-level
> fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.

Also the "Hello 0" is output but not any of the other console logs.

I'd expect the core library to load, followed by the daygrid plugin, but it appears like the plugin is actually loading first, hence the warning in the error.   Isn't the `await` call next to line 3 meant to ensure that. the core library is fully imported before moving on?

Why is that not happening?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I’m having the same problem.

Comment: @levipadre I didn't annoyingly.  I just ended up going back to static imports and that works fine.  If you find a solution please do let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73083051/dynamic-import-with-multiple-modules, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code. This one worked for me:

```
let calendarEl = document.getElementById('fullcalendar');

if(calendarEl) {
    (async () => {
        const {Calendar} = await import('@fullcalendar/core');
        const {default: dayGridPlugin} = await import('@fullcalendar/daygrid');

        let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        
        calendar.render();
    })();
}
```